# How can I control my <h1> styling in another styling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, styling

Hey guys I'm looking to control my `<h1>` styling from another set of styling rules. I know how to do this with `JavaScript` but I'm wondering if I could do this `CSS` only. To get a better example of what I mean check out the example below:

```
h1 {
     color: red;
     opacity: 1;
}

#menu:hover {
      /* Styling for menu bar */
      /* How can I control the style of my <h1> here? I tried:
     h1 {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    but this doesn't work... */
}
```

I hope that gives you an idea of what I'm trying to do... Is this possible with `CSS`?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If the `h1` is descendant of the `#menu`: `#menu:hover h1 { ... }`

Comment: Is the h1 in menu or below, if it's the next element on the page you can go #menu: hover + h1 , or if it's a descendant you can do what @Vohuman said.

Comment: @Crawdingle It's above the menu...

Comment: In that case: You can't.

Comment: @mmgross What if it would be under the menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few specific cases where you can change the styling of 1 element based on the state of another.

**Case 1: `<h1>` is a descendant of `#menu`**

```css
#menu:hover h1 {
  color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <p>Just a paragraph to prove a point</p>
  <div>
    <h1>Another Headline that behaves exactly the same</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Case 2: `<h1>` is a direct descendant of `#menu`**

```css
#menu:hover > h1 {
  color:#f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <h1>Headline</h1>
  <p>Just a paragraph to prove a point</p>
  <div>
    <h1>Another Headline that is not affected</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Case 3: `<h1>` is a direct successor (sibling) of `#menu`**

```css
#menu:hover + h1 {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  This is the div with the id 'menu', hover over it.
</div>
<h1>Headline</h1>
<p>Just a paragraph to prove a point</p>
<h1>Another Headline that is not affected</h1>
```

**Case 4: `<h1>` is any successor (sibling) of `#menu`**

```css
#menu:hover ~ h1 {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  This is the div with the id 'menu', hover over it.
</div>
<h1>Headline</h1>
<p>Just a paragraph to prove a point</p>
<h1>Another Headline that behaves exactly the same</h1>
```

In any other case, for example if `<h1>` precedes `#menu` or they are inside different containers, you're out of luck, there's no way you can do this using CSS alone, but maybe you can use flexbox to reorder your elements so `<h1>` is a successor to `#menu` in your markup but gets rendered above it anyway.

Comment: what do you make of this?  http://jsfiddle.net/L40oz814/ You don't need to specify the element your h1 is placed into when using `~*`

Comment: That's right, nice find, but this will affect every `<h1>` that comes after `#menu` and is a descendant of a sibling of `#menu`, the way I understood OP, only a specific headline should be targeted, but I might be wrong.

Comment: i'm just experimenting with the css, I have found some interesting results, some fails and some that I might find some use of. http://jsfiddle.net/L40oz814/2/ Reason i'm posting this to you is because of the detail in your answer and thought you might be interested another method to target the h1 inside another element as shown in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3):

```
#menu:hover + h1 {
    opacity:0;
}
```

if your H1 is under your menu.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1hyhd5p3/)

Comment: This works but if you put the h1 tag first this won't work. Good answer though, i almost posted the same thing. Out of curiosity, do you know how to do this for elements before the menu? also if you have other elements  between the menu/h1 you can swap the `+` for `~` Example: #menu #somethingElse then your H1 tag.

Comment: Yeah... This is working for me... BUT what if my h1 isn't directly below my menu? Below it but not directly...

Comment: @TheMan I have just edited my comment, swap the `+` for `~` and that should work. http://jsfiddle.net/1hyhd5p3/1/

Comment: @NewToJS Just saw your comment which answered my question! Thanks guys

Comment: The only pure CSS way to do it if the h1 were above would be to position the h1 above the menu within the css, that way it would look like it was above but it would be below in the markup.

Comment: @NewToJS Actually just tried it out and it doesn't seem to work is that cause my #menu is inside another <div>? Its like this `<div><div id="menu"></div></div><h1>Test</h1>`

Comment: You can give that div an `id` for example: http://jsfiddle.net/1hyhd5p3/2/ If you don't want to give your div an `id` you can use this `#menu:hover ~ div h1 {` http://jsfiddle.net/1hyhd5p3/4/

Comment: Yes, they have to be siblings, that means they both have to be children of the same element, see my answer for all cases where you can make it work.

Comment: @TheMan I have just been experimenting with the css and found you don't need to specify the element type or id that your `h1`  is places into. Please look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/kn06wn8u/